# Как с Random'a убрать повторяющиеся цифры, т.е сделать все числа уникальными?

Tags: javascript

Как с Random'a убрать повторяющиеся цифры, т.е сделать все числа уникальными?

Написал:

```
 document.write("<img class='row_size' src=\"img/" + Math.floor(1 + Math.random() * 40) + ".jpg\" />");
```

Но тут появляются повторящиеся цифры. Как сделать их уникальными?

Comment: Смысл тогда Random использовать? Случайные числа предполагают также и появление иногда повторяющихся.

Comment: Уже было: http://hashcode.ru/questions/181199/

Answer (score 2):

Хранить предыдущие результаты работы random'а в каком-нибудь массиве, а при генерации нового числа проверять, есть ли в нём такое. Как-то так:

```
var rand_numbers = [];

function my_rand() {
    while (true) {
        var result = Math.floor(1 + Math.random() * 40);
        if (rand_numbers.indexOf(result) == -1) {
            rand_numbers.push(result);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ухты! Медленно! Так быстрее:
    if (rand_numbers[result] != undefined) ...

Comment: if (rand_numbers[result] != undefined)  не подходит, так как при rand_numbers.push(result) индекс и значение элемента будут разными,
можно совсем чуть-чуть ускорить исходный ответ:
    for(;;) {
    var result = Math.floor(1 + 40 * Math.random());
    if(-1 == rand_numbers.indexOf(result)) return rand_numbers.push(result), result
    }

Comment: А еще можно вместо " if(-1 == rand_numbers.indexOf(result)) " делать проверку так: "  if(~rand_numbers.indexOf(result)) ".

Answer (score 1):

Я новичок в javascript, но я бы сделал как-нибудь так:
1) Заполнил бы массив всеми возможными значениями из которых будет проходить выборка
2) Перемешал бы его
3) Оперировал с каждым его элементом (или частью элементов).
Вот пример, иллюстрирующий эту идею ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/xBQw5/)):

```
function shuffle(o) {
    for (var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i, 10), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
    return o;
}

function range(low, high, step) { // Create an array containing a range of elements
    //
    // +   original by: _argos
    var matrix = [];
    var inival, endval, plus;
    var walker = step || 1;
    var chars = false;
    if (!isNaN(low) && !isNaN(high)) {
        inival = low;
        endval = high;
    } else if (isNaN(low) && isNaN(high)) {
        chars = true;
        inival = low.charCodeAt(0);
        endval = high.charCodeAt(0);
    } else {
        inival = (isNaN(low) ? 0 : low);
        endval = (isNaN(high) ? 0 : high);
    }
    plus = ((inival > endval) ? false : true);

    if (plus) {
        while (inival <= endval) {
            matrix.push(((chars) ? String.fromCharCode(inival) : inival));
            inival += walker;
        }
    } else {
        while (inival >= endval) {
            matrix.push(((chars) ? String.fromCharCode(inival) : inival));
            inival -= walker;
        }
    }
    return matrix;
}
//В этом примере рассмотрим случай, когда нужно выбрать случайное значение от 0 до 4
//Заполним массив всеми возможными значениями
valid_numbers = range(0, 4, 1);
//Посмотрим, что получилось:
console.log('Возможные значения: '+valid_numbers+';');
//Перемешаем его
shuffle(valid_numbers);
//Посмотрим, что получилось:
console.log('Перемешанный массив: '+valid_numbers+';');
//Производим нужные манипуляции :)
valid_numbers.forEach(function (item) {
    console.log("<img class='row_size' src=\"img/" + item + ".jpg\" />");
});
/*
Выведет в консоль:

Возможные значения: 0,1,2,3,4;
Перемешанный массив: 0,1,3,4,2;
<img class='row_size' src="img/0.jpg" />
<img class='row_size' src="img/1.jpg" />
<img class='row_size' src="img/3.jpg" />
<img class='row_size' src="img/4.jpg" />
<img class='row_size' src="img/2.jpg" />
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Заполняем массив, выбираем и переносим из него рандомные элементы в результат:

```
function rand_array(min, max) {
    var m = [];
    for (var i = min; i < max + 1; i++) {
        m.push(i);
    }
    var res = [];
    var len = m.length;
    while (len) {
        var idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * len);
        res.push(m.splice(idx, 1)[0]);
        len--;
    }
    return res;
}
```